# C++ Winsock2 recv junk

Tags: c++, winsock, send, recv

So I am writing a Windows chat and for testing purposes my client program sends a "hello" message to the server every 300 ms.

First couple messages come good but then like for no reason they start to become junk- [image: screenshot]

Obviously I want to fix it and I seek for your help :) Here is my code:

**Send function:**

```
bool Target::Send(char *message)
{
    int length = strlen(message);
    int result = send(this->ccSock, (char*)&length, sizeof(int), 0);
    if (result <= 0)
        return false;

    Sleep(10);

    result = send(this->ccSock, message, length, 0);
    return ((result > 0) ? true : false);
}
```

**Receive function:**

```
Message Server::Receive(SOCKET socket)
{
    int length = 0;
    int result = recv(socket, (char*)&length, sizeof(int), 0);

    Sleep(10);

    char *rcvData = new char[length];
    result = recv(socket, rcvData, length, 0);

    return { rcvData, result };
}
```

**Message struct:**

```
struct Message {
    char *msg;
    int size;
};
```

**Main send code:**

```
while (true)
{
    if (!target->Send("hello"))
    {
        cout << "Connection broken\n";
        target->Clean();
        break;
    }

    Sleep(300);
}
```

**Main receive code:**

```
while (target.sock)
{
    Message message = server->Receive(target.sock);
    if (message.size > 0)
        cout << message.msg << " (" << message.size << ")\n";
    else
    {
        cout << "Target disconnected\n";
        server->Clean();
        break;
    }

    Sleep(1);
}
```

I would really appreciate your help as well as explanation why this is happening!

Comment: TL;DR; Did you take care about proper nul termination of your recv buffer?

Comment: `(result > 0) ? true : false` is equivalent to `result > 0`.

Comment: oh.. didn't know that after 2 years of programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your buffer is not null terminated. So when you are trying to print it using `std::cout` buffer overrun occurs. Correct version of receive code should be:

```
char *rcvData = new char[length+1];
result = recv(socket, rcvData, length, 0); 
rcvData[length] = '\0';
```

Also you never free allocated memory buffer, so your code leaks it on each `Receive` call.

Comment: Thank you, it worked :) I also added `memset(rcvData, 0, sizeof(char) * (length + 1));` after the `new char[]` line

Comment: The `memset()` is overkill, you don't need it at all. And you don't need to null-terminate the buffer if you use `std::setw()` to tell `std::cout` the max number of characters to output: `std::cout << std::setw(message.size) << message.msg;`  However, I would suggest storing the data in a `std::string` instead of a `char[]`, that would take care of the output issue and the memory management issue.